# Use of summary step at the end of Wizard UI?

Tags: modal-windows, wizard, steps

I am designing a wizard about adding events on a calendar. The last step
of the wizard is the summary of the user's choices.

Is it obligatory to use it, or can I skip it?

PS. Number of Steps with Summary: 4.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on how complex the questions are on each page. 4 pages is not a lot so users should be able to remember what they have entered given that each page is asking simple questions.

However I would rather ask myself, whether I really need a wizard for adding an event to a calendar? Wizards are good for splitting up complex tasks, but that doesn't really sound like something that is complex.